# Multi level packages, file paths, and inter sub-package/module imports

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

I'm creating a multi level packages which structure looks like this

```
test.py
main_package/
    sub_package1/
        tables/
            table1.json
            table2.json

        __init__.py # empty
        lib1.py

    sub_package2/
        tables/
            table21.json
            table22.json

        __init__.py # empty
        lib2

    __init__.py # empty
    common1.py
    common2.py
    master_table.json
```

Currently, all the `__init__.py` are empty.

The contents of main_package/master_table.json

```
{
    "group1": {
        "base": "sub_package1/tables",
        "files": [
            "table1.json",
            "table2.json"
        ]
    },
    "group2": {
        "base": "sub_package2/tables",
        "files": [
             "table21.json",
             "table22.json"
        ]
    }
}
```

Within main_package/common2.py

```
import json

class DataTables(object):
    # codes for making this class a Singleton omitted
    ...

    def _process_table(self, table)
        ...

    # will be called from __init__
    def _read_tables(self):
        # the following line throws IOError: file not found
        table_list = json.load(open('master_table.json'))

        for s, desc in table_list.items():
            for f in desc['files']:
                fname = desc['base'] + '/' + f

                # this line also expected to throw IOError
                self._process_table(json.load(open(fname)))
```

in test.py

```
from main_package.common2 import DataTables

test = DataTables()
```

As expected, DataTable._read_tables() fails because the interpreter could not find master_table.json in the same directory as test.py. The code runs fine if common2.py ran directly.

The question is how can I correct this in a flexible way, no matter where in the directory structure test.py is actually located (i.e. in another directory structure).

Another question is how I can test, for example, lib1.py by running it directly when it depends on a function listed in common1.py?

in lib1.py (this won't work)

```
from ..common1 import foo

def this_is_in_lib1()
    ...
    foo()
    ...

ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

while modifying the import like this

```
from main_package.common1 import foo
```

and running it from test.py like this works

```
from main_package.sub_package.lib1 import this_is_on_lib1

this_is_in_lib1()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Modules have a `__file__` attribute that tells you the path to the .py file. Usually,

```
table1 = json.load(open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'table1.json)))
```

in a .py file in that directory is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

About your 2nd question with running `lib1.py` directly, don't do it like that. Don't use arbitrary entry points inside your package. Your package is to be imported by client code, like code in `test.py`. Import the package and make your tests from there, if some inner module is not recognized you need to import its name inside the corresponding `__init__.py`. Or make the tests a subpackage and just use the usual relative paths in the tests subpackage.